# Azure Web Jobs long history affecting app service plan performance

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I have been running my web jobs for a few months now and the history includes hundreds of thousands of instances when some of them ran, mainly TimerTriggers. When I go in the portal to the "Functions" view of web jogs logs I have noticed that my app service plan shoots up to 100% CPU while I am sat on that page. The page constantly says "Indexing...."

When I close the "Functions" view down the CPU goes straight back down to a few percent, it's normal range.

I assume it must be down to the fact that it has been running for so long and the number of records to search through is so vast. I cannot see any option to archive or remove old records of when jobs ran.

Is there a way I can reduce the history of the jobs? Or is there another explanation?

Comment: It's not an answer as such but what I did is move to a new storage account and trash the new one. Saves a bit of money on storage fees too!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Azure Web Jobs, but I am familiar with Azure Functions which is built on top of Web Jobs, so this might work.

In Azure Functions, each execution is stored in Azure Storage Table. There, you can see all of the parameters that were passed in, as well as the result. I could go into the Storage Table and truncate the records I do not need, so you might be able to do the same with Web Jobs.

Here is how to access this information: 
Table Storage in [markheath.net/post/three-ways-view-error-logs-azure-functions](http://markheath.net/post/three-ways-view-error-logs-azure-functions)

[image]

Comment: That's helpful but it's a bit of an omission that there is no facility for this just to happen behind the scenes. Every megabyte of storage costs me a small amount of money as well which all adds up. I notice that for web jobs the equivalent information seems to be stored in blobs.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I checked my webjob and found the related logs for azure webjobs dashboard as follows:

[image]

For Invocation Log Recently executed functions, you could find them as follows:

[image]

**Note:** The list records for Invocation Log are under `azure-webjobs-dashboard\functions\recent\flat`, the detailed invocation logs are under `azure-webjobs-dashboard\functions\instances`.